# Which sequences converge uniformly to $f$?

Tags: analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,+\infty)$ continuous and let $a_n\in \mathbb{R}$ a sequence with $a_n\to 0$. Which of the following statements are correct?

(a) If $f_n(x)=f(x+a_n)$ then $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

(b) (f $f_n(x)=f(x)^{1+a_n}$ then $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

(c) If $f_n(x)=f(x)+a_n$ then $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

(d) If $f_n(x)=(1+a_n)f(x)$ then $f_n\to f$ uniformly.

$$$$

I have done the following :

At (a) we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|f(x+a_n)-f(x)|\leq \epsilon$ with $|x+a_n-x|=|a_n|\leq \delta$ from continuity. So this is true.

(b) is false.

At (c) we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|a_n|\leq \epsilon$ since $a_n\to 0$. So this is true.

At (c) we have $|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|a_nf(x)| $. This is false.

Is everything correct?

Comment: If you are asking if your work is Ok, then it seems to me so: otherwise I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: So (a) is correct, or not? That it follows from continuity of $f$, or not? @DanieleTampieri

Comment: There is no question in the post.

Comment: I edited my post. @innerproduct So are the statements (a) and (c) correct?

Answer (score 1):

a) is false. You proved pointwise convergence and concluded uniform convergence.
For a counter-example let $f(x)=x^{2}$  and $a_n=\frac  1 n$. Uniform convergence would give $|(x+\frac  1 n)^{2}-x^{2}|<\epsilon$ **for all $x$** as long as $n >N$ with $N$ independent of $x$. Obviously the left side can be made as large as you want by choosing $x$ large so the  convergence is not uniform.

Your answer for c) is right. For b) and d) you have to give specific examples to say that they are false. In both cases you can take $f(x)=x$ and $a_n=\frac  1n$

Comment: For (b) we have then : $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=|x^{1+1/n}-x|=|x|\cdot |x^{1/n}-1|$$ The supremum of that expression with $x\in \mathbb{R}$ goes to infinity and that's why we don't have uniform convergence here, right?

Comment: For (d) we have that $$|f_n(x)-f(x)|=\left |\left (1+\frac{1}{n}\right )x-x\right |=\frac{1}{n}|x|$$ The supremum of that expression with $x\in \mathbb{R}$ goes to infinity and that's why we don't have uniform convergence here, right?

Comment: @MaryStar Yes, that is correct.